# Unable to connect to database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting this code correct:

```
$connection=mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
if(!$connection)
{
  die("Database Connection failed".mysql_error());
}

$db_select=mysql_select_db(db_name,$connection);
if(!$db_select)
{
  die("Database Selection failed".mysql_error());
}
```

When I try the script it says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in /home/a8592246/public_html/pic/include/connect.php on line 3

If posssible, can anyone copy and paste the code with the correct settings?

```
$mysql_host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a8592246_dbname";
$mysql_user = "a8592246_dbuser";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";
```

Comment: what is on line no 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use mysql_connect because it is better to use PDO or ADOdb, but lemme give it a try! Try this code :)

```
    $connection=mysql_connect("mysql16.000webhost.com", "a8592246_dbuser", "mypassword");
    if(!$connection)
    {
    die("Database Connection failed".mysql_error());
    }

    $db_select=mysql_select_db("a8592246_dbname",$connection);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
    die("Database Selection failed".mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: Mr Jack, thanks! I got it solved from the above code :)
It was all the help I needed. Im doing this as a hobby so I dont know anything about PDO, ADOdb , msqli etc. only mysql a little bit. (to import) and create tables.
Thanks

Comment: Since I dont have 15 reputation I cant vote up, im sry :/

Comment: If you have php 5.1 or above, PDO is already in. [check this out](http://ca2.php.net/PDO)

Upvoted your question to unlock you from the evil restrictions of new users :)

Answer (score 3):

`}` is missing in second `if` statement, and use correct parameters in `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` functions
Please try this code

```
         $mysql_host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
         $mysql_database = "a8592246_dbname";
         $mysql_user = "a8592246_dbuser";
         $mysql_password = "mypassword"; 



            $connection=mysql_connect( $mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
            if(!$connection){
               die("Database Connection failed".mysql_error());
            }

            $db_select=mysql_select_db( $mysql_database,$connection);
            if(!$db_select) {
               die("Database Selection failed".mysql_error());
             }
```

Comment: I know its missing, its on purpose, I just dont know where to insert:
mysql16.000webhost.com (root)
a8592246_dbname (data base user)
a8592246_dbuser (data base user)
mypassword (data base password)
in the script

Comment: @user3320326 please try undated code

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);

host: you need to write here IP address or the name of the host you are working on eg:
mysqli_connect("localhost",username,password,dbname);

username: you need to mention the username here eg:
mysqli_connect(host,"root",password,dbname); 

password: write password if any.

dbname: write name of the db you want to connect with. eg.
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,"my_db");
```

In your case:

```
$mysql_host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a8592246_dbname";
$mysql_user = "a8592246_dbuser";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";

mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Your provided code  , see below:-

```
$mysql_host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a8592246_dbname";
$mysql_user = "a8592246_dbuser";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";


    $connection=mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    if(!$connection)
    {
         die("Database Connection failed".mysql_error());
    }

    $db_select=mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$connection);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
       die("Database Selection failed".mysql_error());
    }
```

In Your existing code, **$** is missing in **mysql_connect()** function and in **db_name**

Answer (score 0):

try to use  **mysqli**_connect instead of **mysql**_connect

```
<?php

     $con=mysqli_connect(db_server,db_user,db_pass,"database_name");

  /** Check connection **/
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{
      echo "Connection established ";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```